# QML MessageDialog customize on android

Tags: android, qml, messagedialog

Is there any way to customize MessageDialog buttons and appearance on android? I found DefaultMessageDialog.qml file where one can customize some features on desktop and ios but it doesn't make any effect when compiling to android. At least I have to change the buttons' labels to my language.